# freeglut libraries not linking properly. Any way to point the linker to their proper location?

Tags: c++, macos, linker, homebrew, freeglut

I am just trying to display a window using freeglut. I used homebrew to install xquartz, freeglut, and glfw3 because these were the things that the internet told me to install. I then started building a basic application which would simply display a window, but when I tried to compile I got the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_glutCreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in project01-a62b50.o
  "_glutInit", referenced from:
      _main in project01-a62b50.o
  "_glutMainLoop", referenced from:
      _main in project01-a62b50.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The functions the error mentioned are all supported by the freeglut libraries. I have been googling for the past 3 weeks. I am using vs code and compiling using the command line. Below is my incomplete code.

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Initializations
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello World"); 


    //Call main loo=
    glutMainLoop(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

I have tried to compile and link the program with the following.

```
g++ project01.cpp -o project01 -L /usr/local/lib -I /usr/local/include
g++ project01.cpp -o project01 -L /usr/local/opt -I /usr/local/include
g++ project01.cpp -o project01 -lx11 -lxi -lxrandr -lxxf86vm -I /usr/local/include
g++ -o project01 project01.cpp 
g++ project01.cpp
```

I don't really understand the compilation or linking process, however, from what I can tell I am getting this error because the linker cannot find the appropriate library files. I have no idea how to remedy this. If anyone could give me any insight, it would be so huge. Thank you all in advance!!

Best

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was not linking the necessary libraries. I am new to c++ and openGL development, so here is how I ended up compiling my code for those of you who are in the same position as me.

```
g++ project01.cpp -o project01 -lglut -lgl -I /usr/local/include
```

Hope that is helpful.